# How to display category and subcategory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a table with fields: id, name, id_cat
Please show an example of a method that outputs these categories. And where you want to implement this method in the controller or in helpers? Help implement this recursive method.

Comment: @user1233943.. this question is incomplete and not clear. Please make sure you give more details to understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I correctly understand you have Category table with circular reference realised by column id_cat.

Following model should works as you expected:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supercategory, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "cat_id"
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "cat_id"
end
```

So if `categories` table looks like:

```
id   |   name    |  cat_id
---------------------------
1    | cat 1     | null
2    | cat 1.1   | 1
3    | cat 1.2   | 1
4    | cat 2     | null
5    | cat 1.2.1 | 3
```

`Category.find(1).subcategories` returns array with `cat 1.1` and `cat 1.2` objects.

`Category.find(1).supercategory` returns `nil`

`Category.find(3).supercategory` returns `cat 1` object

`Category.find(4).supercategory` returns `nil`

...

Comment: I've added some additional explanations in my answer.